# how to show brand attribute on static block

Tags: product-attribute

[image]I want to show all brand list on category page using static block.

i am using this on `catalog/category/view.phtml`

```
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?> 
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) {
    print $_product->getBrands();
} ?>
```

Comment: that mean current category products brands?

Comment: yes see screen shot. Its give you idea what i need

Comment: is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                  ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
                  ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');
$attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
$manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
?>
 
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer): ?> 
        <li><?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

[Reference](http://www.just4help.info/how-to-get-all-brand-name-in-magento-on-category-product-listing-page/)

**Update**
To include images:

First place your images as `jpg` in `media/brands/your_folder` and change the loop as follow:

```
 <ul>
    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer): ?> 
        <li>
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).str_replace(' ', '-', $manufacturer['label'])."jpg" ?>" width="100" height="100"/>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**Note: your image name must not have spaces and replaced those spaces by "-". For example if your brand name is "My Apple" then file name should be "My-Apple.jpg"**.

For other question, please create separate question.
If it has helped you then please mark it as correct answer, so that someone will get benefited.
Good luck.

Comment: oh thanks very much. You are the first person who help me in magento. I am new to magento i have so many queries. Please help me out on those also. The above code is working fine. can you please tell me how can i show brand image. As you see in screen shot i need to show brands and when i click on that the below product will be filter accordingly that brand. Is that possible?

Comment: @adarsh: I added the attribute option image extension in the backend and  add the images to that particular brands. Now can i get image value of that attribute? I used this extension https://github.com/aligent/magento-attribute-option-image

Comment: I believe that extension added `image attribute` for products, not category. So, you can get that thumb for each image type.

Comment: can i get the brand attribute according to the category? Because right now all the brand come which are not belong that selected category so i want to show particular brand related to that category product. Is that possible?

Comment: is anyone there to help me ?